# Simple condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
if(rule["a:Value"]["0"]._ !== this.state[propertyName].length){
  rett[propertyName] = ""+this.state[propertyName].length 
  rett[propertyName] += rule["a:Value"]["0"]._ 
  rett[propertyName] += "true"  
  return true;
}else{
  rett[propertyName] = "false"
  return false;
}
```

Output:

```
SubsystemID: "00true"
```

First number = first parameter in my condition

Second number = second parametr in my condition

Both are 0. So why my condition go to branch where it should not equal to.. ?

Comment: is `rule["a:Value"]["0"]._` an actual number or a string? Since you're comparing strictly...

Comment: Please build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes probably string and thats the problem. how to improve my code?

Comment: @Bobek a bit of context on what `rule["a:Value"]["0"]._` is would help to know how to fix this. Or you can simply convert it to an integer before comparing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to Federico klez Culloca

```
  if(parseInt(rule["a:Value"]["0"]._) !== (this.state[propertyName].length)){
                                rett[propertyName] = ""+this.state[propertyName].length 
                                rett[propertyName] += rule["a:Value"]["0"]._ 
                                rett[propertyName] += "true"  
                                return true;
                            }
                            else{
                                rett[propertyName] = "false"
                                return false;
                            }
```